# xlwings call from Excel VBA function produces error

Tags: python, windows, excel, xlwings, vba

The call from EXCEL sub to python using xlwings works fine but wen triggering this same VBA via a VBA function the following error is generated:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\a112833\google drive\mytechtests\pulp\mymodule.py", line 13, in energySystemSimulator
    wb = Workbook.caller()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 233, in caller
    xl_app, xl_workbook = xlplatform.get_open_workbook(fullname, hwnd=sys.argv[4])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 142, in get_open_workbook
    duplicate_fullnames = get_duplicate_fullnames()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 124, in get_duplicate_fullnames
    for xl_app in get_xl_apps():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 96, in get_xl_apps
    xl_app = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(hwnd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 73, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    return disp.Application
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.Application
```

This works:

```
Sub eSS()
    RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.eSS()")
End Sub
```

This breaks with the traceback above (ignore fn. arguments):

```
Function fnESS(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    Call eSS
    fnESS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Range("T10")
End Function
```

I checked call signature seems exactly the same using VBA sub or function sub call. I can't see what is causing the error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "triggering VBA via VBA function". Can you add a minimal sample to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @FelixZumstein I have added the additional calling VBA code, also use ver15 64 bit Excel - not sure yet the issues reproduces for 32-bit

Comment: Are you calling fnESS from a Cell?

Comment: @FelixZumstein Yes that's right, the cell contains for example =fnESS(2,4). The reason for this approach is to use the DataTable functionality in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing a common trap when writing User Defined Functions: Excel only allows you to write to the calling cells, not outside of it. That's a limitation by Excel, really.

xlwings might offer a workaround for this one day, but right now, there's no official support for this.

As a side note: you might actually be better off writing UDFs by using the xlwings decorators (at least if you are using Windows only), see [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html).